# Application Cache Error event: Invalid manifest mime type (application/x-ms-manifest)

Tags: manifest

I'm on a shared server, and am using

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

and am getting:

```
Application Cache Error event: Invalid manifest mime type (application/x-ms-manifest) http://www.phillipsenn.com/xxx/cache.manifest
```

Is this something that my hosting company will have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your web server is IIS (Internet Information Server)

The default MIME extension ".manifest" is reserved for ClickOnce deployment (read http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/mime-types-for-clickonce-deployment/)

You can use a different extension for your cache, for example ".mf", but your web server needs to know about its MIME type. In the case of Microsoft IIS, it needs to be added to the MIME Types table:

Extension: .mf
MIME Type: text/cache-manifest

Once you register the new exception you can rename your manifest file, and update the Markup: