# Setting up a cache manifest in IIS

Tags: safari, manifest, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

Q: What mime type do I use instead of application/x-ms-manifest?

My cache manifest is working for Chrome, but not for Safari. Safari is saying "Application Cache manifest had an incorrect MIME type: application/x-ms-manifest".

In IIS7.5, under mime types, I added .manifest with the mime type of application/x-ms-manifest.  It was probably over a year ago, so I don't remember where I got the keywords application/x-ms-manifest.

If I upload my manifest file to the [Cache Manifest Validator](http://manifest-validator.com/), then it validates.
I can also paste the text and it validates as well.

But when I chose to validate by uri, and give it the address to my manifest file:

```
http://www.swatchdog.com/iSwatchDog/Scan/Scan.manifest
```

It says

> Cache manifest must be a plain text file.

Comment: I think changing it to text/cache-manifest made it work.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298823/application-cache-error-event-invalid-manifest-mime-type-application-x-ms-mani) might be where I got the other mime type.